# Share 301 status code URLs on Facebook

Tags: http, http-headers, http-status-code-301, facebook-sharer, tinyurl

When I am sharing a URL which have `301` status code with `Location` header but I found that Facebook didn't fetch contents from destination page but when I share URL of tinyurl.com facebook fetch all contents from destination page and this url also have `301` status code `Location` header, I also want this facility on my URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to lint your URL at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint and fix all errors and warnings listed.

You can lint tinyurl's fine as long as the target location is good. Here's an example of linting a tinyurl:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftinyurl.com%2F6weoofy